# UITextField in NavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c

I just put `UITextField` in NavigationBar using xCode. But when I try to create IBOutlet binding my programm receive `-[UITextField isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`. 
Any suggestions?
Thnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
// configure text field
self.navigationItem.titleView = textField
```

Of course you could also use a property in your view controller instead of a local variable.

Answer (score 3):

You have to call it on the `UITextField`'s `text` property:

```
UITextField *myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:...];
myTextField.text = @"someString";
...
[myTextField.text isEqualToString:@"someString"]
```

Comment: Specially I? I don't.
It mb make OS. But i don't understand where.

Comment: isEqualToString calls before -awakeFromNib method.

Comment: You cannot call it on the class, you have to call it on the instance you have created for a UITextField once you have created the text field.

Comment: You didn't understand. 
In my UIViewController in xCode I put UITextField. Not programmatically.

Comment: Well you still need call it on the UITextField property, NOT on the class

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    UITextField *txtField=[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 30)];
    [txtField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    txtField.text=@"Hello";
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:txtField];
}
```

Will look like..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`isEqualToString` is method of string class not `UITextField`. Thatswhy you get this error. You are passing method to wrong object. Use `textField.text` instead of textField alone

Comment: I don't call isEqualtoString. I have only mainstoryboard, uiviewcontroller, one IBOutlet and this error ;)

Comment: Why are you using uitextfield in navigationBar. Please tell me clearly

Comment: To enter the caption.

Comment: You can use UILabel for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide some sample code or a screenshot if you want a good answer. [May I suggest you read this document for future questions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

This is clearly a case of you calling `isEqualToString` on a `UITextField` when this is a method that must be called on a `NSString`.